# Exclude drafts in all() view of edit.php

Tags: posts, wp-query, customization, wp-admin

The all view shows all posts including drafts in `wp-admin/edit.php`. 
How can I exclude the posts with the draft status in the all view?

Answer (score 8):

The `show_in_admin_all_list` parameter in the [`register_post_status()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_status/) function, determines if a given post status is included in the *All* post table view.

Probably the shortest version is:

```
add_action( 'init', function() use ( &$wp_post_statuses )
{
    $wp_post_statuses['draft']->show_in_admin_all_list = false;

}, 1 );
```

but let's avoid modifying the globals directly like this and override the default `draft` status with:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    register_post_status( 'draft',
        [
            'label'                     => _x( 'Draft', 'post status' ),
            'protected'                 => true,
            '_builtin'                  => true, 
            'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Draft <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Drafts <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => false, // <-- we override this setting
        ]
    );

}, 1 );
```

where we use the priority 1, since the default draft status is registered at priority 0.

To avoid repeating the default settings and support possible settings changes in the future, we could use the `get_post_status_object()` instead:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{   
    $a = get_object_vars( get_post_status_object( 'draft' ) );
    $a['show_in_admin_all_list'] = false; // <-- we override this setting
    register_post_status( 'draft', $a );

}, 1 );
```

Comment: Great, concise answer! One big advantage to this approach is that the post count for all posts is correctly reflected with this code, which is not the case with the answer I posted.

Comment: thanks, I guess there's a workaround to adjust the posts' count for the `pre_get_posts` approach. @DaveRomsey

Comment: I know this is about drafts, but in case someone would like to use this for custom status, be aware there is a bug in WP core https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24415 and in some cases, show_in_admin_all_list might be ignored.

Comment: Thanks @Kokers for the info and the bug link. Hopefully this will be patched.

Answer (score 3):

The code below will remove draft posts from the admin area under the *All* listing for the `post` post type.

The query argument `all_posts` with a value of `1` is added to the menu link to ensure that we're only applying this modification when necessary (The *All* link under the admin post filters (*All, Mine, Published, Sticky, Scheduled, Drafts*)) will add this query parameter for us, but this is not the case when clicking admin menu, so we need to add it ourselves.

Place the code below into your theme's `functions.php` or within a plugin.

```
// Add a query argument to the Posts admin menu.
// This is used to ensure that we only apply our special filtering when needed.
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse255311_admin_menu', PHP_INT_MAX );
function wpse255311_admin_menu() {
    global $menu, $submenu;

    $parent = 'edit.php';
    foreach( $submenu[ $parent ] as $key => $value ){
        if ( $value['2'] === 'edit.php' ) {
            $submenu[ $parent ][ $key ]['2'] = 'edit.php?all_posts=1';
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Hide draft posts from All listing in admin.
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse255311_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse255311_pre_get_posts( $wp_query ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    // Ensure the the all_posts argument is set and == to 1
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['all_posts'] ) ||  $_GET['all_posts'] != 1 ) {
        return;
    }

    // Bail if we're not on the edit-post screen.
    if ( 'edit-post' !== $screen->id ) {
        return;
    }   

    // Bail if we're not in the admin area.
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Ensure we're dealing with the main query and the 'post' post type
    // Only include certain post statuses.
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->query['post_type'] === 'post' ) { 
        $wp_query->query_vars['post_status'] = array (
            'publish',
            'private',
            'future'
        );
    }  
}
```