# Changing labels of status filters for post grid

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Is there a way to change filter labels for custom post type? For example, change `Drafts (2)` to `Disabled (2)` without localization plugins like Loco Translate?

[image]

I've tried `apply_filters( "views_{$this->screen->id}", $views );` filter, but array already contains links with html. Regex doesn't looks "the right way".

```
Array
(
    [all] => <a href="edit.php?post_type=sha-wlc" class="current" aria-current="page">All <span class="count">(13)</span></a>
    [publish] => <a href="edit.php?post_status=publish&#038;post_type=sha-wlc">Published <span class="count">(11)</span></a>
    [draft] => <a href="edit.php?post_status=draft&#038;post_type=sha-wlc">Drafts <span class="count">(2)</span></a>
    [trash] => <a href="edit.php?post_status=trash&#038;post_type=sha-wlc">Trash <span class="count">(1)</span></a>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an untested way to override it, based on my older [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/255319/26350):

```
add_action( 'init', function() {   
    $vars = get_object_vars( 
        get_post_status_object( 'draft' ) 
    );
    $vars['label_count'] = _n_noop(
        'Disabled <span class="count">(%s)</span>',
        'Disabled <span class="count">(%s)</span>',
        'wpse-domain'
    );
    register_post_status( 'draft', $vars );
}, 1 );
```

We use the priority 1, since the default `draft` status is [registered](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/e1b417f5dc17dcdf45ac56ecf1a9e5cdd26039aa/src/wp-includes/post.php#L563) at priority 0.
You might look into the `$vars['label']` as well.

Comment: Thanks! Great solution. I didn't noticed from core `register_post_status` function, that status labels with the same status id merged.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped

Comment: seems like I rejoiced early. Using existing status in `register_post_status` affecting all records, so for default posts this also change labels

Comment: Ok. thx for updates, Yes the status api is not finished aka https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12706. Maybe preg_replace or similar, on your filter can help in the meanwhile.